# Trying to call layered nav block in the list.phtml file - Magento

Tags: php, html, magento

By default in this theme the layered navigation is in the left column, and it is called in the 2columns-left.phtml

```
<div class="col-left sidebar grid12-3 grid-col2-sidebar in-sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
```

When I comment out the php there, it disappears, and if I move it around inside the 2columns-left.phtml file, layered nav moves. However I would like to call this block from inside the list.phtml file instead, because I want layered nav to be contained in the category-products div.

When I put that php in the list.phtml file nothing happens.

I believe the issue is something to do with the catalog.xml file, but I'm not sure exactly how to modify it to get this block called in the file I want.

Here is the code from where it's coming from in the catalog.xml file:

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <!-- <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/su.phtml</template></action> -->
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                    <!--
                        <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>3</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>9</limit></action>
                        <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                    -->
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

If anyone has any idea how I can modify that (or any other layout xml file) to be able to call the layered nav block from inside list.phtml that would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xander ,please try it call to proper place...

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="left">
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav"  template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>


<catalog_category_default translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Non-Anchor)</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>

                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

And also add the below code for call layernaviation on list page list.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('catalog.leftnav'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Sorry I'm still learning my way around developing for Magento.

Comment: The only other thing I'm having trouble with is getting this bit of php to work and show a div based on time and hide it all other times. Posted a new question about it here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076037/hide-div-based-on-time-php