# Hide div based on time - PHP

Tags: php

I'm using Magento, and am trying to hide a div based on time using PHP. I found this bit of code

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$currentHour = date("H");
$openTime = 8;
$closeTime = 9;
if ($currentHour >= $openTime && $currentTime < $closeTime){
$css = 'display:block;';
}else{
$css = 'display:none;';
}

echo '<style type="text/css">.timeBasedLink {'.$css.'}</style>'; ?>
```

And then when I view my websites source (even though right now it is after 9 am, which I've set the time to in PHP just so I could test if it hides, we actually close at 6), it shows up in the header as

```
<style type="text/css">.timeBasedLink {display:block;}</style>
```

no matter what time it is it always shows up as display: block. Might be an error in my code, as I'm still learning PHP.

EDIT: Also does anyone know how to change this to hide it all day Saturday and Sunday? =/

Comment: Review this line once: `if ($currentHour >= $openTime && $currentTime < $closeTime){` Isn't there something wrong with it? :)

Comment: You're using `$currentTime` without setting it anywhere (you probably meant to use `$currentHour` again)

Comment: d'oh. I feel dumb now. That works! Now I just need to implement a way to hide it on Saturday and Sunday.. =/

Comment: This might just be a personal preference, but I'd probably have two CSS classes who's definitions don't change, and then set the class on your `div` or whatever dynamically.

Comment: BTW if you turn on notices with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` (or via your httpd.conf or .htaccess), you won't run into this problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (date("w") == 0 || date("w") == 6 || $currentHour < $openTime || $currentHour >= $closeTime)
{
    $css = 'display:none;';
}
else
{
    $css = 'display:block;';
}
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. The else was just supposed to be display: block. That works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`$closeTime` should be 21 unless you're only open for an hour

Comment: From the OP "even though right now it is after 9 am"  That indicates that the `9` is intentional.

Comment: Nope. I've set it super short so I could test it being hidden. It's just not functioning at all. Figured out the error. I said $currentTime instead of $currentHour. D'oh

Comment: Yep I see that @PatrickQ got that in his comment, I gave him an upvote :P

Comment: Anybody know how I could change this to handle hiding it on saturday and sunday? Would I be better off posting that as a new question.

Comment: If date('w') is 0 or 6 then it's a weekend